# Open sheet when a non-component is clicked, such as a Map Annotation

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I've been attempting to get a sheet to open up when a map annotation is clicked, but I am not having any luck with, so below I will explain what I have:

So inside my MapView, I have the following body:

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State var showActiveMapAnnotation = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                if mainViewModel.selectedItemId != 0 {
                    activeMapAnnotationDisplay
                }
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I had the `activeMapAnnotationDisplay` view that opens up when a map annotation is clicked, so here is the **WORKING** code **WITHOUT** sheets being used:

```
private var activeMapAnnotationDisplay: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        TabView(selection: $mainViewModel.selectedItemId) {
            if let item = mainViewModel.selectedItem {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: PlaceDetailView(place: item),
                    label: {
                        MapPinDetailView(item: item)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: When a user clicks a map annotation, a small modal pops up (`MapPinDetailView`), when the modal is clicked, it redirects to the (`PlaceDetailView`).

**Problem**:
Now, I want to get rid of the small modal completely, and I want to utilize Sheets (https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-bottom-sheet/) introduced in iOS 16, but I am having some issues with the SwiftUI rules, but here is my attempt at `activeMapAnnotationDisplay`:

```
private var activeMapAnnotationDisplay: some View {
    if let item = mainViewModel.selectedItem {
        showActiveMapAnnotation = true
        
        
        // When map annotation is selected, show sheet
        // When sheet is clicked, open PlaceDetailView
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $showActiveMapAnnotation, content: {
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                ScrollView {
                    // Things will go here
                }
                    .presentationDetents([.large, .fraction(0.3)])
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I know this isn't anywhere close to being done or right, but I don't know how to properly take an approach on this, so I wanted to see if I could get some help.

Here is ultimately what I'm aiming for:

1. When user clicks a map annotation (`mainViewModel.selectedItem`), it shows a sheet instead of `MapPinDetailView`.
2. When user clicks on the sheet, navigate them to the `PlaceDetailView` view.

---

I came across this error:

`Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type` on `private var activeMapAnnotationDisplay: some View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your example without more context, but maybe your should change the logic.
Why you just don't use an .onChange for viewModel.selectedItem, where selectedItem should be a @Published

```
.onChange(of: viewModel.selectedItem, perform: {
   showActiveMapAnnotation = true
})
```

Pease give me more info about the view where you want the sheet to be displayed, and I can help you more.

Comment: Hey Marta, so inside `MapView.swift`, I have the `@EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel` defined, which selects `mainViewModel.selectedItem`. Inside `MainViewModel.swift`, I have the following variable:     `var selectedItem: Place? { places.first(where: {$0.id == selectedItemId })}` and `@Published var selectedItemId = 0`. Thanks for attempting to help me on this! I will give that a shot also.

Comment: I don't really understand what's in your activeMapAnnotationDisplay view ... You should just add the onChange and the .sheet in the mapView.

Comment: struct MapView: View {
    @State var showActiveMapAnnotation = false
    var body: some View {
         /// your view details here
.onChange(of: viewModel.selectedItem, perform: {
   showActiveMapAnnotation = true
})
.sheet(isPresented.... 
/// your sheet here
}